# Post-by-mail similar to WordPress.com or Posterous?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, posts, wordpress.com-hosting, email

A standard WordPress installation has very basic support for [posting via e-mail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email). Is there a plugin that gives [the same functionality as WordPress.com](http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-by-email/) (especially attachment handling)?

My client is in love with Posterous, and I could set up [the XML-RPC bridge](http://posterous.com/help/autopost) so new posts go to WordPress, but I'd rather stay in WordPress so I could add advanced handling of custom post types and taxonomies myself once we get the basics running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Postie.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postie/

It has lots of features (including handling attachments and inline images)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it out and accept your answer if it works for me!